# Function not running/being called properly

Tags: javascript, function, switch-statement

The variable `vTotalPayment` is not working. I assume this is due to how I am calling function, though I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am aware this also might be due to misuse of the switch statement.

```js
function begin() {
  var vTicketType = prompt('Please enter the type of ticket');
  var vTicketQty = Number(prompt('Please enter amount required'));

  document.write('Ticket Type: ' + vTicketType + '<br />');
  document.write('Ticket Qty: ' + vTicketQty + '<br />');

  var vTicketPrice = calcPrice(vTicketType);
  var vTotalPayment = calcTotal(vTicketQty, vTicketPrice);

  document.write('Total Payment: ' + vTotalPayment);

}
begin();

function calcPrice(Prices) {
  var Price = 0;
  switch (vTicketType) {
    case 'A':
      Price = 100;
      break;
    case 'B':
      Price = 75;
      break;
    case 'C':
      Price = 50;
      break;
    default:
      Price = -1;
  }
  return (Price);
}


function calcTotal(Payments) {
  var Payment = (vTicketQty * vTicketPrice);
  return (Payment);
}
```

Comment: When you are calling the function then you are using 2 parameters but in your function definition you have only 1 parameter. May be thats wrong. You need to use both  vTicketQty and vTicketPrice as the parameter. Try that. Like this.... function calcTotal(vTicketQty,vTicketPrice) {
    var Payment = (vTicketQty * vTicketPrice);
    return (Payment);
}

Comment: Its because, you didn't declared the variables you are using like

In function calcPrice : you are passing `vTicketType` to switch statement instead of Prices 
and also in function `calcTotal` you are using undefined variables.

Comment: You can try this as a replacement for switch. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gzfyzy4h/).  Note this is optimisation. Answer below have pointed out actual reason for problem

Answer (score 1):

You are only passing one argument to function calcTotal and not even using it. Replace your calcTotal with below code and let me know in comments if it's still not working.

```
function calcTotal(vTicketQty, vTicketPrice) {
    return (vTicketQty * vTicketPrice);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your methods have wrong parameters. Wrong number of parameters and wrong names.

Instead of `calcPrice(Prices)` I think it should be `calcPrice(vTicketType)` and instead of `calcTotal(Payments)` it should probably be `calcTotal(vTicketQty, vTicketPrice)`

```js
function begin() {
    var vTicketType = prompt('Please enter the type of ticket');
    var vTicketQty = Number(prompt('Please enter amount required'));

    document.write('Ticket Type: ' + vTicketType + '<br />');
    document.write('Ticket Qty: ' + vTicketQty + '<br />');

    var vTicketPrice = calcPrice(vTicketType);
    var vTotalPayment = calcTotal(vTicketQty, vTicketPrice);

    document.write('Total Payment: ' + vTotalPayment);

}
begin();

function calcPrice(vTicketType) {
    var Price = 0;
    switch (vTicketType) {
        case 'A':
            Price = 100;
            break;
        case 'B':
            Price = 75;
            break;
        case 'C':
            Price = 50;
            break;
        default:
            Price = -1;
    }
    return (Price);
}


function calcTotal(vTicketQty, vTicketPrice) {
    var Payment = (vTicketQty * vTicketPrice);
    return (Payment);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```js
(function begin() {
    var vTicketType = prompt('Please enter the type of ticket');
    var vTicketQty = Number(prompt('Please enter amount required'));

    document.write('Ticket Type: ' + vTicketType + '<br />');
    document.write('Ticket Qty: ' + vTicketQty + '<br />');

    var vTicketPrice = calcPrice(vTicketType);
    var vTotalPayment = calcTotal(vTicketQty, vTicketPrice);

    document.write('Total Payment: ' + vTotalPayment);

})();

function calcPrice(vTicketType) {
    var Price = 0;
    switch (vTicketType) {
        case 'A':
            Price = 100;
            break;
        case 'B':
            Price = 75;
            break;
        case 'C':
            Price = 50;
            break;
        default:
            Price = -1;
    }
    return Price;
}


function calcTotal(vTicketQty, vTicketPrice) {
    var Payment = (vTicketQty * vTicketPrice);
    return Payment;
}
```

For best practice, you do not need () parenthesis when you return Payment or return Price